# Can't send JSON as string via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So I'm trying to send a JSON as a string.
Then I have a PHP back-end that retrieves this JSON string and parses it using `json_decode`.

Unfortunately, I can't get to send this JSON as a string.

Here's the jQuery Ajax script I used:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(checkables);
console.log(jsonString);

$.ajax({
    url: $url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {ajaxidate: JSON.stringify(jsonString)},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    success: function (data)
    {
        // just successful callback
    },
    error: function ()
    {
        // just error callback
    }
});
```

Variable `checkables` contains raw form as JSON data:
[image: checkables_data]

After applying `JSON.stringify()`, this is now how it looks:
`[{"name":"name","type":"multialphanumslug","value":"AD"},{"name":"server","type":"host","value":"10.1.1.1"},{"name":"port","type":"number","value":"8080"},{"name":"authid","type":"username","value":"barryallen"}]`

At the back-end, I have this PHP script:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    die();
?>
```

Now I suppose $_POST at back-end should now contain this:

array(
    'ajaxidate' => "[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"multialphanumslug\",\"value\":\"AD\"},{\"name\":\"server\",\"type\":\"host\",\"value\":\"10.1.1.1\"},{\"name\":\"port\",\"type\":\"number\",\"value\":\"8080\"},{\"name\":\"authid\",\"type\":\"username\",\"value\":\"barryallen\"}]"
);

But it didn't receive anything. Here's the captured request:

[image]

The response from back-end?

[image]

I tried with POSTMan and I received an expected correct output:

[image]

Now that was ridiculous.

I'm stuck at this for 2 days trying to figure out what's going on or what did I miss. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you sending it as string? instead you should send it as JSON object.

Comment: `$myArray = json_decode($_POST['ajaxidate']);`?

Comment: if you wanna send as string then why using  dataType: 'json'   ???? remove data type : json ,

Comment: @Munna `dataType: 'json'` will parse the response - from the server - as JSON and give an object / array as first argument to the success callback

Comment: @Munna updated my question and removed the `dataType: 'json'`, still not working

Comment: @AmitSoni no, it is a complex JSON object and POST does not support posting complex multi-dimensional JSON objects

Comment: @dev-null I get your point, but I'm investigating first why $_POST doesn't have `$_POST['ajaxidate']`? It doesn't send what I'm trying to send, it doesn't make sense

Comment: have you tried $.post(URL,data,callback); ???  @AllenLinatoc

Comment: @Munna `$.post` is just an alias for `$.ajax({type: post})`

Comment: Thanks @Munna, your suggestion to use $.post() taught me how to consider simple things out of complexity. I still prefer to use $.ajax() though, makes me feel like I have lots of choice. But that made me figure out that `contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"` is the culprit. After removing that, it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the data on the server:

```
$myArray = json_decode($_POST['ajaxidate']);
var_dump($myArray);
```

Consider this:

```
<?php
    $a = '[{"a": 1}]';
    $b = json_decode($a);
    var_dump($a);
    var_dump($b);
?>
```

Output:

```
string(10) "[{"a": 1}]"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

`dataType: 'json'`, tldr: Use It!

When setting dataType = json you tell jQuery that the response from the server should be interpreted as JSON and it will therefore parse it for you and give the parsed object / array as first argument to the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
   // ...
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(myJson) {
     console.log(myJson); // this will be a JSON object/array...
   }
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your help @dev-null but I'm done with the back-end part. I'm already finished designing it with complex processing procedures. And I already stated that in my question: *"Then I have a PHP back-end that retrieves this JSON string and parses it using json_decode."*

Answer (score 0):

As you mention `dataType: json`  in your  `ajax` call data need to be in json formate  but using `JSON.stringify` convert Json object to json String that with make problem for you need to change

```
 `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(checkables);`
```

to

```
 var jsonString = checkables;
```

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Thanks, but POST doesn't support sending multi-dimensional JSON objects

Comment: @AllenLinatoc Where did you read that information? [It is](https://www.zulius.com/how-to/send-multidimensional-arrays-php-with-jquery-ajax/) absolutely possible to send multi dimensional JSON objects via ajax POST.

Comment: @Novocaine yes it is possible to send JSON objects via AJAX **as a string** and requires `json_decode()` at PHP back-end (which I just did from my question), but not as JSON object itself to be sent directly via POST.

Comment: @AllenLinatoc that's not accurate. You will notice in the example I linked, data is not being converted into a string before the ajax call. If you're passing data that is already a JSON object, there is no need to `JSON.stringify()` it. Not only does the example show that, but I have done it this way successfully many times. It's worth noting this is only the case v1.4.0 and up.

Comment: @Novocaine are you referring to Method #1 from your source? It says: _"I don't recommend this method because it does not maintain the JS array's original structure in the Javascript"_ Besides, that's an array, not JSON. Now if you're referring to Method #2 and #3, those are using `JSON.stringify()` just like what I used. If you want, try it yourself sending a raw complex JSON directly. That didn't end good in my case. Hehe

Comment: problem is he is using POST to get  JSON objects at server side instead of file_get_contents('php://input'), that's why he said "but POST doesn't support sending multi-dimensional JSON objects"

Comment: @AllenLinatoc No I'm not referring to Method 1, 2 or 3. Those are all for versions below v1.4.0. If you are using 1.4.0 or above which like I said you should be, then you need only look at the very first example (the section *BEFORE* Method 1). Obviously the way you've done it now does work, but I'm trying to show you that there is a cleaner way to do it. Your current method is more complicated than it needs to be, both in client side and server side codes.

Comment: @Novocaine ahh ok ok, seen it, haha. _"Your current method is more complicated than it needs to be, both in client side and server side codes"_ yes I agree to this. Thanks mate for pointing it out, noted on that version. I just hope the same way applies for Angular (as well).

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. Having @Munna suggested to use $.post() made me figure out to eliminate the unnecessary. From that case, the unnecessary is `contentType` option from $.ajax().

This is the updated working solution:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {ajaxidate: JSON.stringify(jsonString)},
    success: function (data)
    {
        // just successful callback
    },
    error: function ()
    {
        // just error callback
    }
});
```

Thanks everyone who helped. Have a good day